# Convert dotcloud sandbox flavor to live flavor?

Tags: dotcloud

Is there any way to convert an existing "sandbox" dotcloud deployment to a "live" flavor?
Or do I have to destroy and recreate it?

There are two reasons I want to do this:
1) preserve the old name of my app ... i.e. the subdomain on dotcloud.com
2) avoid minor hassle of moving my database data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You yourself can't change it yet, but if you head over to our [support page](http://support.dotcloud.com) and file a ticket, we'd be happy to upgrade your application flavor.

**Update**: I'm told we only offer the conversion for Legacy apps so if you're a sandbox user then you'll have to push a new app or destroy the sandbox app before re-pushing it as Live. Please see http://docs.dotcloud.com/0.4/guides/flavors/ for more details on how flavors work.

Answer (score 1):

No. It's right there in the docs and of course I found it right after posting:

"You can’t change the flavor of an application once it has been pushed, so take the time to choose the right one!"
http://docs.dotcloud.com/0.4/guides/flavors/